# What's the best way to create a contextual menu in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, menu, wordpress-theming

I want to display a contextual menu for example in the RedProducts section I want the menu to show:

```
RedProduct1 
RedProduct2
```

etc, and also the same for BlueProducts, GreenProducts etc when they're selected.

Also it'd be great if these links can display a different class when they're selected. So for example:

```
<ul>        
<li class="link"><a href="/redproduct1" >Red Product 1</a></li>     
<li class="current"><a href="/redproduct2" >Red Product 2</a></li>      
<li class="link"><a href="/redproduct3" >Red Product 3</a></li>
```

Comment: In the time since I created this question I've found that Wordpress automatically marks up the current link with the class "current-menu-item", so it's only the 1st part of my question I'm unsure about.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit more or show some sketches or image of what you are trying to achieve.?

Comment: Sure, I want my 1st level nav to show: 
RedProducts
GreenProducts
BlueProducts

Then if you click either of these (lets use red as example), the 2nd level nav shows:
RedProduct1
RedProduct2 etc

Answer (score 2):

The Wordpress plugin "Advanced Menu Widget" now does this all for you, very quick and simple, took me ages to find it though.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are trying to do this. [**jsfiddle example**](http://jsfiddle.net/libinvbabu/QbX7k/).

This is how the "contextual menu" works. :) Simply hiding the sub menu and upon clicking the primary menu, it will open with the help of jQuery!

Just apply this to your WordPress menu. Don't forget to include the jQuery library.